# How to relocate column names based on a specific order, if some names are missing in the dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, relocate

I am trying to use the relocate() function to reorder the columns of a dataframe based on a specific order. The order is not alphabetical. E.g.

| Red | Yellow | Green | Brown | Blue | Pink | Black | White |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

The data could be different each time it is loaded in. For example, it might be as follows (with no column for Blue):

| Black | Brown | Green | Pink | Red | White | Yellow |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 8 | 2 |

When I try to relocate based on the full ordered listing, e.g.

df %>% relocate("Red", "Yellow", "Green", "Brown", "Blue", "Pink", "Black", "White")

I then get the following error:

Error in `relocate()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `Blue` doesn't exist.

I don't want to specifically list the dataframe as I don't know what columns will/won't be included each time. Is there a way to order the column based on the full list even if some column names are missing?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `any_of`:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Black = c(6L),
  Brown = c(5L),
  Green = c(2L),
  Pink = c(1L),
  Red = c(3L),
  White = c(8L),
  Yellow = c(2L)
)

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  relocate(any_of(c("Red", "Yellow", "Green", "Brown", "Blue", "Pink", "Black", "White")))
#>   Red Yellow Green Brown Pink Black White
#> 1   3      2     2     5    1     6     8
```